# Install python environment without sudo

Tags: python, root, conda

I am using a server with Python 3.4. I need to use Python 3.6.4 with some packages. I therefore created an environment with conda using

```
conda create --name myname python=3.6.4
conda install --name myname --file spec-file.txt
```

where `spec-file.txt` was created from a conda on another machine in order to clone that enviroment.

However, when I try to run my script, it seems I don't have the permission to access them.

```
(myname) [myname@myserver my_folder]$ python myscript.py -img_lst_fp /home/myname/my_folder/myserver_pictures.csv -out_fl /home/myname/my_folder/output.csv
bash: /home/myname/.conda/envs/myname/bin/python: cannot execute binary file

(myname) [myname@myserver my_folder]$ python
bash: /home/myname/.conda/envs/myname/bin/python: cannot execute binary file
(myname) [myname@myserver my_folder]$ ./myscript.py -img_lst_fp /home/myname/my_folder/myserver_pictures.csv -out_fl /home/myname/my_folder/output.csv
bash: ./myscript.py: Permission denied
```

Is there a way to solve this without requesting the intervention of a root user?

EDIT: I have no idea why but now I cannot even execute "python"

Comment: Seems like `./myscript.py` doesn't have the execute bit set. You can chmod it or do `python ./myscript.py`.

Comment: It might also be something wrong with the python binary. Are you sure it is built for the same architecture? https://superuser.com/a/436081

Comment: Edit before: I cannot even execute python.

Comment: It could be that the other machine where you built the spec has a different architecture. _Conda does not check architecture or dependencies when installing from a spec file. To ensure that the packages work correctly, make sure that the file was created from a working environment, and use it on the same architecture, operating system and platform, such as linux-64 or osx-64._
 
https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#building-identical-conda-environments

Comment: [How to share conda environments across platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280638/how-to-share-conda-environments-across-platforms)

Comment: To check that the platform of the two machines are the same you can use the command `uname -oi`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
pip install --user virtualenv
```

Comment: OP is using conda instead of pip and virtualenv.