# What is the recommended way to distribute a custom python environment?

Tags: python, pythonpath, python-venv

## The problem

I want to distribute some custom python packages to computing nodes.  The installation path is not the same as the build path, so paths can't be hard-coded. The setup process should be no more complicated than `source /path/to/MyOrgCode/setup.sh`, and ideally should not require downloading or re-installnig everything.  I see several potential methods to do this, all of which seem to have major drawbacks.

### Some background to give a concrete example

The high energy physics community uses a tool called [CVMFS](https://cernvm.cern.ch/portal/filesystem) to distribute compiled executables, libraries, and data files to nodes on computing clusters. In general, you compile your code on a machine with the same architecture as the nodes, then publish to a central repository. So I might build my code in `/home/user/MyOrg`, which when published would appear on a compute node at `/cvmfs/MyOrg.opensciencegrid.org` . To make this portable, you provide a setup script that might look something like

```sh
# MyOrg setup.sh script
export PATH="`dirname $0`/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="`dirname $0`/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

This way everything is always set up relative to wherever the setup script is installed, and so the whole directory tree can be moved around and renamed easily. Somehow I cannot see a simple way to do the same thing with python packages.

## Options for distributing python packages

### 1) Use virtual environments

I can craete a virtual environment alongside my 'bin' and 'lib' directories, copy the whole thing, and  then just call `source /path/to/MyOrgCode/venv/bin/setup.sh` in my setup script. But:

- virtual environments use hardcoded paths, so I can't move them by default
- `virtualenv` has the `--relocatable` option, but there are lots of warnings about how it can mess things up. Plus, as far as I know, `virtualenv` is considered deprecated in favor of `python -m venv`
- Since the venv would generally be installed somewhere without write permissions, users wouldn't be able to install further custom packages for development, since `pip install --user` doesn't function in a venv.

### 2) Install on demand

Have a `pip install -r requirements.txt` line in my setup script. This has a number of potential problems:

- Where to install? A `--user` install will pollute the user's default python setup and may have unexpected consequences.  Could use a venv, but then where do we put it?
- This is really inefficient if packages have lots of code to compile or large datasets included
- If my python packages are on a private VCS, I need to distribute access credentials with my setup script, which in general will be readable to anyone who knows the URL.

### 3) Use PYTHONPATH

However many python packages I have, put them all in my repository and then add an entry for each one to PYTHONPATH in my setup script. Potential problems:

- I seem to remember being told that modifying PYTHONPATH is something of a last resort, though right now I can't find any evidence to support that.
- If the packages are located on a can it be compiled (i.e. generate .pyc files?)  Is there a command I can run to force compilation before distribution?

## Conclusion

Is there a recommended way to do this sort of thing? Is there a different method than the ones I've thought of, or a way around the pitfalls?

Comment: you can use conda for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280638/how-to-share-conda-environments-across-platforms or also use docker to make a container with the needed packages: https://www.docker.com/

Comment: @MasonCaiby docker is a no-go as it is not widely enough supported on computing nodes (you generally have to take extra steps to make sure you get a c++11 compatible compiler!) conda is a possibility, though heavier weight than I'd like