# save the virtual environment in Anaconda and share it with other colleagues

Tags: python, conda

I have an virtual environment created in Anaconda. How to save this environment and share it with my colleague, so that they can just use it without re-creating it. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share conda environments across platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280638/how-to-share-conda-environments-across-platforms)

Comment: Not sure about "*without re-creating it*". While there are things like [`conda-pack`](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/), exporting the env (`conda env export > environment.yml`) and recreating it is the Conda idiom. Note that using flags like `--from-history` or `--no-builds` can be helpful if sharing across platforms.