# PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels (libgcc-ng and libstdcxx-ng)

Tags: python, linux, yaml, conda

I am trying to run the yml file but fail to solve the environment. The error is

```
ResolvePackageNotFound:

libgcc-ng
libstdcxx-ng
```

Then I tried conda installs

```
conda install -c anaconda libgcc-ng 
conda install -c conda-forge libstdcxx-ng
```

but the following error occurs:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

libgcc-ng
libstdcxx-ng

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
```

Edit:
I tried ([PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493505/packagesnotfounderror-the-following-packages-are-not-available-from-current-cha))

```
conda config --append channels conda-forge
```

and then tried

```
conda install -c conda-forge <package>
```

as well as pip install. Still does not work as my goal is to download libgcc-ng and libstdcxx-ng packages

Comment: This might help. You may have to use pip or install the channels you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493505/packagesnotfounderror-the-following-packages-are-not-available-from-current-cha

Comment: Tried conda config --append channels conda-forge and then tried conda install -c conda-forge <package>, as well as pip install. Still does not work

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? What are you trying to compile?

Comment: @merv My goal is to download libgcc-ng and libstdcxx-ng packages so that I can  run the set up part

Comment: YAML files are not meant to transfer across platforms, so you should not insist on installing exactly the same packages on your **osx-64** machine as were installed on a **linux-64** machine. If you can, ask whoever has access to the original environment to export using this command: `conda env export --from-history`. That is less prone to include platform-specific packages (though not  guaranteed).

Comment: merv is right. You just can't install them on macOS from the `environment.yml` file. The yml is not cross-platform compatible. `libgcc-ng`, `libstdcxx-ng` are only libraries for `gcc`. The following answers help you get these libraries from other approaches.

Comment: Hi @merv and @Simba, thank you so much for your message. I am trying to follow the github repo, build up a conda environment with `conda env create --force -f ../mimic_extract_env_py36.yml`. However those two libraries make me cannot make the environment working. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Edit the YAML file to remove what is not compatible with your platform ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39280638/570918)). Otherwise, run a Docker or something equivalent where you can run Linux.

Answer (score 4):

`libgcc-ng`, `libstdcxx-ng` do exist in `conda-forge`. But they're for **Linux only**, not for macOS, Windows.

- [conda-forge/libgcc-ng](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/libgcc-ng)
- [conda-forge/libstdcxx-ng](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/libstdcxx-ng)

These two packages include libraries for gcc. For macOS, install `gcc` with homebrew. They are contained by the `gcc` package already.

```
brew install gcc
```

Comment: Hi, are there other methods to download those two packages? Once I use your command, the error shows that gcc: the bottle needs the Xcode CLT to be installed. However Xcode is too big for my computer

Comment: @ZhangYongheng Xcode command line tool is not Xcode. Xcode CLT is more lightweight. Use `sudo xcode-select --install` to install it.

Answer (score 3):

As [@Simba correctly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68845839/570918) those packages are for **linux-*** platforms only. If your goal is simply to have a C/C++ compiler (not specifically GCC), consider instead using

```
conda install -c conda-forge compilers
```

This will install a platform-appropriate compiler on each platform, and populates the environment variables `CC`, `CXX` and `GFORTRAN` with paths to the respective compilers.

Comment: Hello, I used your command and still wondering what is the next step if I want to download libgcc-ng and libstdcxx-ng packages? Thank you!

Comment: @ZhangYongheng if you want those particular packages, then my answer is not what you should follow. My answer addresses if you just need a compiler and not specifically GCC. Maybe you could expound upon your end goal (edit original question), not just the particular problem.